# How to skip any category in seo meta title template?

Tags: category, category-tree, category-attribute, category-listing

We have magento 2 on website we have 4 categories, we sell photocopier parts, let me give an example what issue we are facing and what we want.

Konica Minolta - Bizhub Color Series- Bizhub 203 - Toner Cartridges

Category 1 - Category 2 - Category 3 - Category 4

We have magewrox seo suit installed on website , we made a template for meta titles when we call categories in this template the meta title goes like this

"Konica Minolta Bizhub Color Series Bizhub 203 Toner Cartridges"

We want to skip series category in seo templates , but when we change the sequence like Category 1 - Category 3 - Category 4 on different pages and stages it catches the sequence at current stage of ccategory breadcrumbs and does not skip. We want to show this category to customers but want to hide and skip it in meta titles. We talked with magewrox they said that it is not possible in their extension. Do we have any customization in which we can show category on front end but it should be hidden in seo templates. Like on any page when we call category 2 in any template it should not consider the series category it should consider next one as category 2. Hope it make sense if you dont understand I will try to elaborate it more